# Kafka to presto querying the raw json topic

Tags: json, apache-kafka, presto

I'm pushing a JSON file into a Kafka topic, connecting the topic in presto and structuring the JSON data into a queryable table.

The problem I'm facing is that the table doesn't show any entires in it, even though the topic has been populated with some data.
This is what gets displayed,

```
presto:default> select * from test;
 kafka_key | host | method | endpoint | protocol | status | response_time | uuid
-----------+------+--------+----------+----------+--------+---------------+-----
(0 rows)
```

Before including the mapping file it displayed the JSONs and I could query the field _message
Where am I going wrong? Is it in the description file ?

The JSON looks like this

```
{"host":"17.33.69.92","method":"GET","endpoint":"\/health\/info?access=afbadb4ff1435c0ed1b2976439a90cc4","protocol":"HTTP\/1.1","status":200,"response_time":3,"uuid":"892a1847-0f98-4327-8f56-3135915e96aa","time":"2020-02-11 00:00:01"}
```

and the default.test.json file in etc/kafka is as below:

```
{
    "tableName":"test",
    "schemaName":"default",
    "topicName":"default.test",
    "key":{
        "dataFormat":"raw",
        "fields":[
            {
                "name": "kafka_key",
                "dataFormat": "LONG",
                "type": "BIGINT",
                "hidden": "false"
            }
        ]
    },
    "message":{
        "dataFormat": "json",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "host",
                "mapping": "host",
                "type": "VARCHAR"
            },
            {
                "name": "method",
                "mapping": "method",
                "type": "CHAR"
            },
            {
                "name": "endpoint",
                "mapping": "endpoint",
                "type": "VARCHAR"
            },
            {
                "name": "protocol",
                "mapping": "protocol",
                "type": "VARCHAR"
            },
            {
                "name": "status",
                "mapping": "status",
                "type": "INTEGER"
            },
            {
                "name": "response_time",
                "mapping": "response_time",
                "type": "INTEGER"
            },
            {
                "name": "uuid",
                "mapping": "uuid",
                "type": "VARCHAR"
            },
            {
                "name": "time",
                "mapping": "time",
                "type": "TIMESTAMP"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I followed this [tutorial](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/kafka-tutorial.html) as reference.

Thank you.

Edit1:
The table and data are present.
[image]

Comment: Can you please share the Presto version that you are using? You can enable more logging to get more details about what happens, to do so in PrestoSql 3xx you can add `io.prestosql.plugin.kafka=DEBUG` to your `log.properties`

Comment: can you run show create table and look in the location to see if there is actual data present?

Comment: @kokosing I have presto version 0.230. I tried the logging part, initially I had other topic names in kafka.properties file so there were logs of error from that. I checked again to make sure the topic names were removed and the properties file looks exactly like the one in the above. The Previous error was `Error injecting constructor, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: `, but after that there are no errors logged in the server.log file. Where could the issue be exactly?

Comment: @bdcloud I've edited the post with a screenshot, is that what you required?

Comment: If you find this troubleshooting doesn't really fit SO model, you can use the `#troubleshooting` on the [Presto community slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html).